# Reset commits on a given branch to author's info (e-mail, date, etc.)

Tags: git

I tend to `amend` and `rebase` a lot since I do small commits and usually group (read: `squash`) them in the end to have a coherent (like in nice) history.

Being said that, I would like to have the same info from **author** and **committer** for every commit in a given branch, so I was wondering if there was a way to do this "natively" with Git.

Basically, what I'm looking for is:

- Take all the commits from branch (compared to `master`), e.g.: `git rev-list master..HEAD`
- Retrieve the author's date from a given commit (e.g.: `git log --format=%aD --no-walk`) and apply the change(s)

In that way, the committer's info is the same as the author's info — because nothing else changes for my case, except the dates.

I know can do this interactively, but I was wondering if there was a Git-fu command that would let me do such thing.

Comment: Is *niceness* the goal here? Or does current history cause a real problem somewhere?

Comment: What's the benefit of doing this? Do you rebase onto the latest origin/master before you submit and/or complete your PR? (Because if yes, this is pointless.) Or if someone suggests a change during the code review, aren't you going to just rewrite those committer dates again anyway?

Comment: I want this to avoid the notifications for some of the work that I have to fix for some co-workers, so I keep the author's info intact, and they keep the notifications for themselves. As soon as I put my info, I'm a contributor for that work and I start receiving notifications for that repo, which I don't usually work on. Otherwise I would have to change the `user` and `email` continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter-branch supplies the standard utility functions (from `libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup`) to the filters you run, so

```
git filter-branch \
        --setup 'eval `get_author_ident_from_commit thatcommit`
                 targetname=$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
                 targetemail=$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
        ' \
        --env-filter '
                 GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$targetname
                 GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$targetemail
                 GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$targetname
                 GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$targetemail
        ' \
        --tag-name-filter cat \
        -- master..
```

To do this with belt-and-suspenders, do it in a scratch clone:

```
git clone -ns --mirror . `mktemp -d`; cd $_
# the above filter-branch
# if everything looks good, 
git push origin HEAD
cd -
```